# What am I doing wrong in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

android = [82.8, 84.8, 79.8, 69.3]
android2 = [float(i) for i in android]

ios = [13.9,11.6,12.9,16.6]
ios2 = [float(i) for i in ios]

win = [2.6,2.5,3.4,3.1]
win2 = [float(i) for i in win]

years = [2105,2014,2013,2012]
years2 = [float(i) for i in years]

plt.bar(years2,android2, color='blue')
plt.xticks([2012,2013,2014,2015])

plt.show()
```

It is supposed to look [like this](http://courses.cs.purdue.edu/_media/cs17700:spring16:labs:bar_graph.png?cache=):

[image]

I am confused as to why my graph squeezed all of the x values together and did not
space them out. And how do I make each of my bars a certain width like the one
in the image?

Answer (score 4):

Because you have 2105 in your "years" list, it's bigger than others so change it to smaller value like 2005 or 2015.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the typo @Metin noticed, you also need to change the bar width, and then offset each set of bars by that width, to reproduce this plot.

Following [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html), you can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

android = np.array([82.8, 84.8, 79.8, 69.3])
ios = np.array([13.9,11.6,12.9,16.6])
win = np.array([2.6,2.5,3.4,3.1])

years = ['2015','2014','2013','2012']

index = np.arange(len(years))

bar_width = 0.3

plt.bar(index, android, label='android',
        width=bar_width, color='blue')
plt.bar(index+bar_width, ios, label='ios',
        width=bar_width, color='red')
plt.bar(index+2*bar_width, win, label='win',
        width=bar_width, color='yellow')

plt.xticks(index + 1.5*bar_width, years)

plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]